# Moving the last table cell above the first on media query

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm just starting out with foundation and its really powerful.

Is there a way to make the right cell go above the left cell when the responsive design is actioned? Currently the image goes beneath, but I'd like it to go above.

Is this possible?

I've tried (as you can see below, switching the "first" and "last" classes, but this does not work.

```
<table class="row">
  <tr>
    <th class="small-12 large-7 last columns" style="font-size:12px !important;padding-left:30px !important;color:#414141 !important">


    <span style="font-size:20px;color:#0171c5">
    This is a title about things in this email and things</span>
    <br /><br />
      Test
      <br />
      <br />
<a href="#" style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;color:#0171c5">Read More</a>
    </th>
    <th class="small-12 large-5 first columns" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 6px !important;text-align:center">
        <img src="images/2nd-image.jpg"  style="max-width:100%;height:auto;margin-left:auto" />
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```